# Intent filter for PACKAGE_ADDED for a specific package

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

In my Android app, I'm catching the PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnAppInstall">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My app is only concerned with installation of a specific companion app. The data string in the intent goes: `package:com.acme.myapp`. The intent data Uri is an instance of `OpaqueUri`; `getHost()`, `getPath()`, and `getQuery()`  all return nulls.

Can I somehow make an intent filter that only allows intents for one specific package ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
<data android:scheme="package"
      android:sspPrefix="com.acme.myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

This matches with the corresponding API call [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addDataSchemeSpecificPart(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: Android 4.4+ only. Still, better than nothing. At least on earlier versions, it doesn't prevent the filter from working.

Comment: Ran on 5.0 emulator, with the sspPrefix the receiver doesn't fire, without it does :(